# Understanding probability density functions through an example

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am trying to clarify a fundamental concept regarding probability and density functions. Please bear with me if it is silly.

Say, I need to define the likelihood of two people meeting (random variable $X$) just based on the distance ($y$). And if we assume that they are likely to meet as the distance between them decreases.

Can I say that the probability $p$ that they meet is given by, $p=e^{-y^2}$ ? If yes, why? For my doubt is that this does not qualify to be a density function.

Comment: Well, if you have a probability density function $f$, surely the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ has to be equal to $1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not a probability density function, but you don’t want a probability density function; you want a probability. It’s perfectly possible that the probability of the two people meeting is $\mathrm e^{-y^2}$. A probability density function would be required if the distance were a random variable, e.g. if they were to meet at a random distance. Then indeed $\mathrm e^{-y^2}$ would not be a suitable probability density function for the distance $y$, since it’s not normalized. A suitable probability density function for $y$ might be $\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\mathrm e^{-y^2}\mathbb 1[y\ge0]$ (where $\mathbb 1[y\ge0]$ is the indicator function that is $1$ for $y\ge0$ and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: Thank you. One doubt that I have is, shouldn't the probabilities sum up to one. In using $e^{-y^{2}}$, I get a value belonging to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @user206089: Which probabilities in the plural? There's only one probability here, $\mathrm e^{-y^2}$, the probability for the people to meet. The only thing it should sum up to $1$ with is the probability $1-\mathrm e^{-y^2}$ that they won't meet. If you think otherwise, please state specifically which probabilities you think should sum up to $1$.